# Unable to Import Model Into an other Model Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have Suppliers Model from a Purchase Module and  i am simply import it in my Inventory Module.

> Here is my Purchase Module Model Supplier

```
from django.db import models
from django_countries.fields import CountryField

from Inventory.models import productDetails,products
from Accounts.models import elementaryhead
from datetime import datetime
import base64

# Create your models here.
class suppliers(models.Model):
    companyName=models.CharField(max_length=30,verbose_name='Company Name')
    companyAddress=models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name='Company Address')
    city=models.CharField(max_length=20,verbose_name='City')
    region=models.CharField(max_length=20,verbose_name='Region')
    country=CountryField()
    postalCode=models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Postal Code')
    companyPhone=models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Company Phone")
    companyFax=models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Company Fax')
    elementaryID=models.ForeignKey(elementaryhead,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None,null=True,verbose_name='Elementary head',editable=False)
    buyer=models.BooleanField(default=None,verbose_name='Is Buyer',editable=False)
    supplier=models.BooleanField(default=None,verbose_name='Is Supplier',editable=False)
    website=models.URLField(default=None,verbose_name='Website')

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
             update_fields=None):
        accountID = elementaryhead.objects.order_by('id').last().id + 1
        code = '00003-000010-0000' + str(accountID)
        subhead=10
        elementaryhead.objects.create(subhead_id=subhead, name=self.companyName,fixed=False, codes=code, right=True)
        accountID = elementaryhead.objects.order_by('id').last().id + 1
        subhead=11
        code = '00003-000011-0000' + str(accountID)
        elementaryhead.objects.create(subhead_id=subhead, name=self.companyName+'(I/TAX PAYABLE)',fixed=False, codes=code, right=True)
        accountID = elementaryhead.objects.order_by('id').last().id + 1
        subhead=15
        code = '00003-000015-0000' + str(accountID)
        elementaryhead.objects.create(subhead_id=subhead, name=self.companyName+'(GST W/HELD PAYABLE)',fixed=False, codes=code, right=True)
        self.supplier = True
        self.buyer = False
        super(suppliers,self).save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.companyName
```

> Here is my Inventory Module Model InventoryIn

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from Purchase.models import suppliers,contracts
class inventoryIn(models.Model):

    supplierID=models.ForeignKey(suppliers,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Supplier')
    productID=models.ForeignKey(products,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    purchaseContractID=models.ForeignKey(contracts,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    unitsIn=models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Units In')
    doID=models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Do ID')
    doImage=models.ImageField(upload_to='/assets/image')
    invoiceID=models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Invoice ID')
    invoiceImage=models.ImageField(upload_to='/assets/image')
    agingDate=models.DateField()
    dateOfEntry=models.DateField(default=datetime.now())
    def __str__(self):
        return self.supplierID
```

I am basically add two ForeignKey(supplierID,purchaseContractID) which relates to Purchase module.But its throws an error that

> ImportError: cannot import name 'suppliers'
>   And i had tried to import it within the InventoryIn Model Class. But its didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for circular import. But you can by pass this by following

```
class inventoryIn(models.Model):

    supplierID=models.ForeignKey('Purchase.suppliers',on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Supplier')
    productID=models.ForeignKey(products,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    purchaseContractID=models.ForeignKey('Purchase.contracts',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    unitsIn=models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Units In')
    doID=models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Do ID')
    doImage=models.ImageField(upload_to='/assets/image')
    invoiceID=models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Invoice ID')
    invoiceImage=models.ImageField(upload_to='/assets/image')
    agingDate=models.DateField()
    dateOfEntry=models.DateField(default=datetime.now())
    def __str__(self):
        return self.supplierID
```

And also don't forget to remove this import

```
from Purchase.models import suppliers,contracts
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a circular import. One of your Python files imports from the other, and then also vice versa. That leads to this kind of problem -- B tries to import from A while A is still being set up.

The easiest solution is to put them all into one file, another hacky solution is to import the other module only within the `save` function (so it happens later).

The better solution is to take a hard look at your data model to see why there is this circularity in this and whether that is really necessary, as it's often a sign of a bad design.

Answer (score 0):

You have a circular import. But there doesn't seem to be any reason for you to be importing the Inventory models into Suppliers at all, since you're not using them in that file. Remove the import.

Answer (score 0):

can you try something like:

```
supplierID=models.ForeignKey('Purchase.suppliers',on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Supplier')
```

instead of importing the model